# What are function conversion rules for parameters in C?

Tags: c

I have understood how the conversion rules are for expression but I cannot find where or sum up to conversion related to function arguments. Any help please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- If the argument matches a declared parameter from a function prototype, it is converted to that type.
- Otherwise, there is either no function prototype or the prototype ends in `...` and the argument matches the ellipsis, and the argument undergoes the *default argument promotions*.

Example:

```
void f(char, int, ...);

signed char a = 'x';

f( 25.8    // converted (truncated) to char matching parameter
 ,    a    // converted (promoted) to int matching parameter
 ,    a    // default-promoted to int (not matching any parameter)
 ,  1.f)   // default-promoted to double (not matching any parameter)
```

Comment: Perhaps you could elaborate on the default argument promotions.

Comment: Is the first line of code prototype or not a prototype ?

Comment: @Sabrina: It is a prototype.

Comment: Ok then what is a definition containing a prototype and Is a definition considered a prototype?

Comment: I feel a never-ending Q&A coming up... can you update your question, or perhaps ask new question, or even better search for existing answer to further questions you may have? Or consult the reference 6.5.2.2 for which you asked earlier?

Comment: (A definition always includes a prototype. A declaration that is not a definition is a just a declaration (not a prototype) if it's like `void f();`, and it's a prototype if it contains a parameter list, like `void f(void);`, `void f(int);` or `void f(int, ...);`.)

Comment: Just this **last question**: if the defintiion included a prototype what is meant by `If the function is defined with a type that includes a prototype,` and `If the function is defined with a type that doesn't includes a prototype,` it is confusing !

Comment: That really doesn't fit in this margin... sigh. OK, what this is referring to is this: in `a.c` you say `void f(); int main(void) { f(a); }` (same `a` as above). This gets promoted. Now in `b.c` you *define* `void f(signed char) { ... }`. Now the type of the argument after promotion in the call (`int`) does not match the type of the parameter of the function defined with prototype (`signed char`), and that's UB. (This is saying that the prototype for this `f` needs to be visible at the point of the call, so that no promotion happens.)

Answer (score 0):

Basically this is obsolete, functions have prototypes. But it lives on in variadic functions where you don't have a proper prototype. In reality these seem to be used almost exclusively for printf() style format strings, and most compilers have special case code built in to warn about non-matching types.

But shorts and chars are promoted to int, and floats are promoted to double. long integers remain long (so they need the %ld format), there's also long long (%lld format).

Comment: Why you are answering as if there is printf in my question ??